# How to create a dictionary with two list and same key

Tags: python, list, sqlite, dictionary

i have a problem. I've obtained a group of information from my sql database. But when i want to convert these information in a python dictionary, the key is correct, but i get just the last element of the list. How can i obtain this? '{{'fruit': 'apple','orange'},{'car': 'mustang', 'porche', 'ferrari'},{'mobile': 'Apple','Samsung'}'

```
sql:
('fruit','apple')
('fruit','orange')
('car','mustang')
('car','porche')
('car','ferrari')
('mobile','Apple')
('mobile','Samsung')

a_list = [fruit,fruit,car,car,car,mobile]
b_list = [apple,orange,mustang,porche,ferrari,Apple,Samsung]
a_dict = {}
for key in list1:
    for value in list2:
        a_dict[key] = value
        list2.remove(value)
        break

print(a_dict)
```

Output: {'fruit':'orange','car': 'ferrari','mobile': 'Samsung'}

Answer (score 1):

you can use a list of dictionary, for example:

```
list=[{'fruit':'orange','car': 'ferrari','mobile': 'Samsung'},{'fruit':'mango','car': 'honda','mobile': 'nokia'}]
```

even for do iteration is more easy, for example:

```
for x in list:
   if x['fruit']=='mango':
      #do something
```

Comment: I had written a simplification, the information which i want to tabulate are more and more, i can't write all those information.